# derivative of scalar function w.r.to another scalar function - with the arguments being matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives

As stated in the comments, I will specify my problem in more detail:

$\boldsymbol A = A_{ij} \boldsymbol e_i \otimes \boldsymbol e_j$ is a symmetric tensor tensor of 2nd order.

The first invariant of $\boldsymbol A$, i.e., the trace and its derivative w.r.to $\boldsymbol A$ are given by:

$I_{\boldsymbol A} = \mathrm{tr} \boldsymbol A \\
\frac{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A} }{\partial \boldsymbol A} = \frac{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A} }{\partial A_{ij}} \boldsymbol e_i \otimes \boldsymbol e_j = \boldsymbol I
$

The third invariant of $\boldsymbol A$, i.e., the determinant and its derivative w.r.to $\boldsymbol A$ are given by:

$III_{\boldsymbol A} = \det \boldsymbol A \\
\frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A} }{\partial \boldsymbol A} = \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A} }{\partial A_{ij}} \boldsymbol e_i \otimes \boldsymbol e_j = \det (\boldsymbol A) \boldsymbol A^{-1}
$

There is a scalar function $E$ dependent on the first and third invariant of $\boldsymbol A$:

$E = E(I_{\boldsymbol A}, III_{\boldsymbol A} )$

A symmetric 2nd order stress tensor is then defined as:

$\boldsymbol S = \frac{\partial E}{\partial \boldsymbol A} 
= \frac{\partial E}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A} } \frac{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} +  \frac{\partial E}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A} } \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A}$

What I want to compute is a 4th order tensor as follows:

$\boldsymbol L = \frac{\partial \boldsymbol S}{\partial \boldsymbol A} = \frac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial A_{kl}} \boldsymbol e_i \otimes \boldsymbol e_j \otimes \boldsymbol e_k \otimes \boldsymbol e_l \\ \boldsymbol L =\frac{\partial \boldsymbol S}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}} \otimes \frac{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} + \frac{\partial \boldsymbol S}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}} \otimes \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial \boldsymbol S}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}} \\ = \frac{\partial}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}} \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A} } \frac{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} +  \frac{\partial E}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A} } \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} \right) \\ = \frac{\partial}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}} \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}} \right) \frac{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} +  \frac{\partial E}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A} } \frac{\partial}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}} \left(  \frac{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} \right) +  \frac{\partial}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}} \left( \frac{\partial E}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}} \right) \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} +  \frac{\partial E}{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A} } \frac{\partial}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}} \left(  \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} \right)$
\

The last summand is given by:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}} \left(  \frac{\partial III_{\boldsymbol A}}{\partial \boldsymbol A} \right) = \frac{\partial \det (\boldsymbol A) \ \boldsymbol A^{-1} }{\partial I_{\boldsymbol A}} = \frac{\partial \det (\boldsymbol A) \ \boldsymbol A^{-1} }{\partial \mathrm{tr} \boldsymbol A}  = \frac{\partial \det (\boldsymbol A) \ A^{-1}_{ij} }{\partial \mathrm{tr} \boldsymbol A} \boldsymbol e_i \otimes \boldsymbol e_j $

After applying product rule, I come up with the derivative

$\frac{\partial \det (\boldsymbol A)}{\partial \ \mathrm{tr} (\boldsymbol A)} $ .

I would appreciate to get proposals how to calculate this expression.

Comment: Is there some other problem you have in mind you hope to tackle in a way that requires this partial derivative to make sense? If you tell us of such a problem in a question edit, maybe we can suggest either an alternative method or how to parameterize $A$ to make the partial derivative well-defined.

Comment: @J.G. I edited my question such that you can see how I actually derived this "partial" derivative. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @J.G. Do you think you can provide me keywords which you think may be helpful to solve my issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is a meaningless question as written. Knowing only how the trace is changing is simply not enough information to tell you how the determinant is changing. To calculate a partial derivative you need to specify not just what is changing but what is being *fixed*; in other words you need to specify a set of coordinates on the space of matrices which includes $\text{tr}(A)$. This choice of a set of coordinates is not unique and different ones will produce different values for the partial derivative.

Comment: Computing the partial derivative w.r.to trace(A) means, at least in my case, that all off-diagonal entries of A are being fixed. Is it possible to compute the derivative as stated with that additional information?

Comment: @Simon Not quite. If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, fixing the off-diagonal entries leaves $n$ degrees of freedom. To define a partial derivative, you need to fix another $n-1$. Even if the off-diagonal entries are all $0$, your question reduces to the still meaningless "derivative of the eigenvalues' product with respect to their sum".

Comment: @J.G. This makes sense. But, lets say I want to compute the derivative of det(A) wrt tr(A). What is an appropriate approach to do this? I think I am on the wrong right now.